# Stitching DHT and Torrent Client together

Tags: java, bittorrent, dht, torrent, kademlia

I have two java libraries.
One connects to DHT and can successfully download torrent files.
And the other which downloads the actual data associated with the torrent.

The torrent client library expects an announce or announce-list section in the torrent, and does't understand the 'nodes' entry.

The question is how do I alter the torrent client code to understand the 'nodes' section of a torrent file.
OR
How do I calculate a tracker URL from a set of ip:port DHT peer addresses?

I could just guess the url by guessing a port number and appending /announce onto it.. but this surely isn't right?

Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For DHT-only operation you do not need an announce URL. If the library itself expects one you can insert a dummy url, the format `dht://<infohash in hex>` is common, but it does not matter, as it won't be used.

The DHT part on the other hand does not require the `nodes` to perform a lookup, it simply operates based on the infohash of the torrent. The nodes can *optionally* be injected into a dht client for bootstrapping, e.g. by executing a ping on them, but that should not be needed if it already is bootstrapped.
Once the DHT client has done its `get_peers` and `announce` lookups the peer lists can be injected back into the torrent client.

Since you're using my library: You can use [PeerLookupTask](https://github.com/the8472/mldht/blob/d547b4ecf7d081f6763e09a502b610313eb30ed9/src/lbms/plugins/mldht/kad/tasks/PeerLookupTask.java) to read a torrent peer list from the DHT and [AnnounceTask](https://github.com/the8472/mldht/blob/d547b4ecf7d081f6763e09a502b610313eb30ed9/src/lbms/plugins/mldht/kad/tasks/AnnounceTask.java) to add your torrent port to the list. The obtained IP and Ports have to be passed to the torrent client. The [GetPeers](https://github.com/the8472/mldht/blob/d547b4ecf7d081f6763e09a502b610313eb30ed9/src/the8472/mldht/cli/commands/GetPeers.java) CLI command contains an example how to use the first part.
There also are [utility methods](https://github.com/the8472/mldht/blob/d547b4ecf7d081f6763e09a502b610313eb30ed9/src/lbms/plugins/mldht/kad/DHT.java#L546-L573) that should cover common use cases.

Comment: So.. dht bootstraps.. i search for a torrent hash and the torrent file itself comes down but contains no information on how the torrent client should find peers.. so it cannot download the files.. how can i use dht to get the torrent client some peers?

Comment: By the way... well done on the dht client. Your java 8 coding is the best i've seen.

Comment: the torrent client library is ttorrent (turn) by the way.

Comment: Note my last sentence, if you don't know the tracker for the torrent - e.g. if none are included in the magnet link - you will also have to use the DHT to obtain peers and tell the torrent library about it.

Comment: But how. my limited understanding is that dht and bittorrent are separate protocols running out of separate ports. I know what dht peer ip's and ports i have... i'm fairly sure those peers are also torrent peers, but i need to know what port the torrent client is listening on? can you recommend a document to read that explains your comment?

Comment: http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html is the spec. "But how. my limited understanding is that dht and bittorrent are separate protocols running out of separate ports." yes, but so do bittorrent peer-peer connections and the http connection to a tracker. the point is that the DHT gives you a peer list which you can then plug into the torrent library, assuming the library has such an interface

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding.. what query can i make on dht that will get me ip's and ports that a torrent client can use to download torrent fragments? From what i can see dht can only find other dht peers, which are not exactly the same as torrent peers because the port number is dofferent?

Comment: Can PeerLookupTask be modified to filter peers that do not support encryption (header, or header and fragment)? Does it do that already?

Comment: @Richard that information is not stored in the DHT, only PEX, extension protocol handshakes and some (rarely used) tracker extensions provide it. If you have further questions you can [ask on github](https://github.com/the8472/mldht/issues). SO comments are hardly appropriate for this.

Comment: Ahh.. thanks... BEP 8 seems to suggest that I would have to query each peer.. 
I don't suppose I could be cheeky? I have a list of questions as long as my arm.. This doesn't seem like a good forum for it. Is there any way I could communicate with you in a longer format? Perhaps through GitHub? Or some other way that you would find acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative I may recommend you to see Bt, which is a Java 8 BitTorrent client and already integrates with the8472's mldht: https://github.com/atomashpolskiy/bt

Comment: Isn't it underpinned by compiled binaries? I really need a pure java implementation, and there don't seem to be any.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer by the way. I really would like a torrent client that can handle rc4 stream encryption.

Comment: I'm implementing something lilke flexget by the way.

Comment: Yes, it's 100% pure Java. I'm actively developing it for almost a year now and plan to do so in the foreseeable future. Which means that I'll be able to quickly provide help if you get stuck or add a missing feature upon request.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. The current client is not working for me... i suspect because of isp packet filtering..

Comment: That would certainly be an issue. Why do you think so, are you not getting any bittorrent traffic? They might also use simpler methods, like blocking certain ports and trackers. Anyways, message stream encryption and BEP-8 are among the stuff that I'm planning to do, might as well revisit it now.

Comment: Yes no traffic. But it could be something else.. spent my time on the caching and feed reading for now. Will integrate bt this week. I'll let you know how i get on. Need to learn more about dht too. There seems a lot of magical trafic on the dht which might be interesting.

Comment: Hi Richard! I was wondering how it's going with this project of yours. I've added encryption support in Bt and would be really excited if you could give it a try and let me know if it helped with the traffic problem! Thanks

Comment: Its going well considering I only have 2 hours a day on it.
I've been working on the caching, RSS reading, admin http server and torrrent processing.I'm about to get started on the actual bittorrent client stuff this weekend I hope. I'm persisting with the client I have for now. But when I have something worth sharing, if you're interested I'll give you access to the SVN server and you can have a look at it. You might find a way to take what I've done and make use of it yourself.